# how to find rows with white spaces in a dataframe, using python?

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, where-clause, whitespace

I have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a DataFrame

df1 = {
    'State':[' Arizona AZ ',' Georgia GG ', ' Newyork NY','Indiana IN ','Florida FL '],
   'Score1':[62,47,55,74,31],
   'Score2':[332,'',35,73,61]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['State','Score1','Score2'])

print(df1)
```

it returns

```
          State  Score1 Score2
0   Arizona AZ       62     62
1   Georgia GG       47       
2    Newyork NY      55     35
3   Indiana IN       74     73
4   Florida FL       31     61
```

now I want to add another column to judge 'pass' if I have value for both Score1 and Score2, and 'fail' when one is blank.

I thought the bellow do the work but didn't.

```
df1['pass/fail'] = np.where((df1['Score1'].isspace()) | (df1['Score2'].isspace()) , 'fail',' ')
```

How can I add a column to find out if I have data for both columns or not?

edit: my dataset actually looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Create a DataFrame

df1 = {
    'State':[' Arizona AZ ',' Georgia GG ', ' Newyork NY','Indiana IN ','Florida FL '],
   'Score1':[62,47,55,nan,31],
   'Score2':[332,'',35,73,61]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1,columns=['State','Score1','Score2'])

print(df1)
```

both 'nan' and ' ', must return a fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert them to strings by `astype(str)` then use `.str.fullmatch` with a regex `\s*` that checks if the entry is either empty (blank space) or full of spaces e.g. `''` or `'  '` etc.:

```py
df1['pass/fail'] = np.where(
                        (df1['Score1'].astype(str).str.fullmatch(r"\s*") |
                         df1['Score2'].astype(str).str.fullmatch(r"\s*")),
                        'fail',
                        'pass')
```

to get

```
          State  Score1 Score2 pass/fail
0   Arizona AZ       62    332      pass
1   Georgia GG       47             fail
2    Newyork NY      55     35      pass
3   Indiana IN       74     73      pass
4   Florida FL       31     61      pass
```

If you want to avoid repetition in there, you can wrap the masks in a function:

```py
def is_blank_mask(df, column):
    return df[column].astype(str).str.fullmatch(r"\s*")
```

and then

```py
df1['pass/fail'] = np.where(is_blank_mask(df1, 'Score1') |  is_blank_mask(df1, 'Score2'),
                            'fail',
                            'pass')
```

Comment: thank you @Mustafa Aydın , I just realized that in some rows(in my real dataset) instead of "white spaces" I have "Nan", could you please give me some extra advice?

Comment: Aydin  for example I have a line with these two     "9000.00" and  "nan".  how can handle them

Comment: @sam_sam Change the inside of the fullmatch above to `fullmatch(r"\s*|nan", flags=re.IGNORECASE)` to handle nans (also making sure to look for case-insensitive matches via `re.IGNORECASE` e.g. also match `Nan` etc.).

Comment: you made my day! Thank you so much.